# Django UserCreationForm not showing errors

Tags: html, django, forms

I have a very simple sign up template in django. This form is just not working, wether it's valid or not.

**the html code:**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    {{ form.errors }}
</body>
</html>
```

**the view:**

```
def test(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        redirect('index')
form = UserCreationForm()
return render(request, 'test.html', {'form': form})
```

I expect to get redirected back to the index page if the form is valid, and get the form errors if it's not valid. I end up not getting anything in return - only the chrome prompt that suggests saving my details.

Comment: You shouldn't reassign the form, you need to return the form with REQUEST.POST to get the return errors message

Comment: @LinhNguyen Thank you so much! such a dummy mistake!!

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't loop the errors properly.

```
{% if form.errors %} {% for field in form %} {% for error in field.errors %}<p> {{ error }}</p> {% endfor %}{% endfor %}{% endif %}
```